# Weblogic 12.2.1.3 from Moxy to Jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, weblogic12c, jackson2

I would like to change the JSON parser from Moxy to Jackson, and I have followed the [shared library approach](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLPRG/libraries.htm#WLPRG331), but without any result, Moxy is still used.

**Note:** the shared library is not necessary!!!

### <del>The shared library</del>

I have created a maven project with the following dependencies and descriptors.

#### <del>pom.xml</del>

```
 <properties>
    <jackson.annotations.release>2.8.6</jackson.annotations.release>
    <jersey.version>2.22.4</jersey.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.annotations.release}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.annotations.release}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependency>
```

#### <del>weblogic.xml</del>

```
 <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <!-- apis -->
        <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>

        <!-- guava -->
        <package-name>com.google.common.*</package-name>

        <!-- jersey providers -->
        <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</package-name>
        <package-name>jersey.repackaged.*</package-name>

        <!-- hk2 -->
        <package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.tiger_types.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javassist.*</package-name>

        <!-- media providers -->
        <!--<package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.*</package-name>-->
        <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>

        <!-- wls -->
        <package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.api.client.*</package-name>
        <package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.internal.api.client.*</package-name>
        <package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.dispatch.*</package-name>
        <package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.monitoring.util.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

#### <del>MANIFEST.MF</del>

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Jackson Weblogic
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title: Jackson Weblogic
Extension-Name: jackson-weblogic
Specification-Version: 1.0
```

### <del>Web Application</del>

I add the `web.xml` and the `weblogic.xml`.

#### <del>web.xml</del>

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.dummy.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.dummy.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

#### <del>weblogic.xml</del>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>jstl</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.2</specification-version>
        <implementation-version>1.2</implementation-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>jackson-weblogic</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.0</specification-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

<del>Then I reference in the `weblogic.xml` the shared library, but Moxy is still used. Have I done something wrong?</del>

<del>**Update:** I have added the `web.xml` and the `weblogic.xml` of the web application.</del>

## Solution

I have checked the folder `oracle_common\modules` and I have found all the `Jackson` dependencies needed. So I have preferred to configure `Jersey` to disable the use of `MOXy` as follows:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties()
    {
        Map<String, Object> proprties = new HashMap<>();
        proprties.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);

        return proprties;
    }
}
```

**Pay attention:**

- that the method `getProperties()` comes with `javax.ws.rs 2.0`;
- no specific shared library is necessary for `Jackson`, but just for `jstl` <del>and `jax-rs 2.0`;</del>
- no info inside `web.xml` is required;
- as reported by @abbas JAX-RS 2.0 comes by default with Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 in my case I has a transitive dependency on `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api` so the method `getProperties()` was not invoked.

#### Final weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">

    <context-root>/web-app</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.apache.commons.net.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>

    <library-ref>
        <library-name>jstl</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.2</specification-version>
        <implementation-version>1.2</implementation-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: If both are on the classpath, MOXy will always win out, unless you explicitly register the `JacksonFeature`.

Comment: @peeskillet do you mean what I have added in the `web.xml`? or is it better to register the feature in a different way? Jax-rs 2.x uses SPI-based auto-registration so I have though it was not necessary the `web.xml` but even with it `weblogic` still uses `moxy`. Thanks for your time ;-)

Comment: @peeskillet thanks again, I think I have found another solution, I have tested in WildFly as well and it seems there are no drawbacks so far.

Comment: at least you do not need to library-ref for JAX-RS 2.0 because it is now part of Weblogic 12.2.1

Comment: @abbas the lib JAX-RS 2.0 is under the folder `wlserver\common\deployable-libraries` and as far as I have understood it has to be deployed otherwise the method `getProperties()`, part of specification 2.0, is not called. I suspect that Weblogic by default uses the old library.

Comment: Check this sample project which I created last night

https://github.com/esafzay/jax-rs-2-java-ee-6-weblogic-12.2.1

Comment: @abbas thanks a lot, you are right, it is not necessary to deploy the shared library JAX-RS 2.0, the issue on my side was to due to `swagger` having a dependency on `jsr311` and so loading wrong version, once I removed it everything was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mention JAX-RS 2.0 as a dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In WebLogic 12.2.1 you do not need to deploy it as a shared library.